# Setting default value office ui fabric react people picker

Tags: react, office-ui-fabric-react

I'm currently using the CompactPeoplePicker component however I'm looking to extend it using the selectedItems property to set the people picker from a rest call.

```
<CompactPeoplePicker
            onResolveSuggestions={this._onFilterChanged.bind(this)}
            onChange={this._onPersonChanged.bind(this)}
            itemLimit={1}
            className={"ms-PeoplePicker"}
            selectedItems={this.state.riskOwner}
/>
```

This is the code I'm currently using for the people picker, my state.riskOwner is a userID I'm storing in a SharePoint list however I'm uncertain what properties I need to pass back to the selectedItems and the documentation is unclear.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ref. your comment, here's how it works:

You resolve suggestions using `onResolveSuggestions`, i've explained it below. When you've resolved people you want to store them in your state and set them using the `selectedItems` attribute. `selectedItems` should contain an `Array<IPersonaProps>`.

`onResolveSuggestions` can take a `Promise` as input. You should resolve to an array of `IPersonaProps`.

Here's a shortened code for my PeoplePicker implementation, in the actual solution i've added a setTimeout that clears out every time the function is called, that way you don't overload the system with irrelevant requests.

I've created a helper function called `SPUtilities.searchUsers` that simply returns a `Promise<Array<IPersonaProps>>` with the users that match the filtertext.

```
onFilterChanged(filterText: string, currentPersonas: IPersonaProps[], limitResults?: number) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {            
        SPUtilities.searchUsers(filterText.toLowerCase()).then((result: Array<IPersonaProps>) => {
            resolve(result)
        })
    });
}
```

My helper-function users the built in UserInformationList and the ListData.svc to query it, since the SharePoint REST api currently doesn't have a good tolower-function. I've shortened it and simplified it a little, also note that the UserInformationList is localized so it may be named something else in your language.

```
public static searchUsers(title: string): Promise<Array<IPersonaProps>> {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {            
        var filter = "substringof('Account',tolower(" + title + "))";
        $.ajax({
            headers: { "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose" },
            url: _spPageContextInfo.siteAbsoluteUrl + "/_vti_bin/listdata.svc/UserInformationList/?$top=10&$select=Account,Title,ID,WorkEmail,Picture&$filter=" + filter,
            success: (result: ListDataResponse) => {                    
                var users = result.d.map((item) => {
                    var pictureUrl = (item.Picture !== null) ? item.Picture : "";
                    return  {
                        title: item.Title,
                        id: item.ID,
                        imageUrl: pictureUrl,
                        primaryText: item.Title,
                        secondaryText: item.WorkEmail
                    } as IPersonaProps;                         
                });                    
                resolve(users);
            }
        });
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Let me answer your actual question; `selectedItems` takes an `Array<IPersonaProps>`.

Comment: Would you be able to explain how I'd practically use this? Can I store the  array IPersonaProps in a People or Groups field in a SharePoint list then populate it using this?